# How are excavation permits handled if the turn you dig in straddles a year-end?

Tags: thebes

In Thebes, you're an archaeologist digging up ancient ruins around the turn of the 20th century. When you show up at a dig site, and dig for some variable amount of time, you expend your excavation permit for that site. There are five sites to dig at, and your excavation permits are restored when you complete a game year.

The trouble is that the duration of a turn is variable in Thebes; you spend one week for every space you move, and up to 12 weeks digging. It's quite possible for one of your digs to straddle a year-end: you start before the year ends, and finish sometime in the new year.

**Can you dig at a site if you have no permission, using the "refreshed" permit to dig?** (And thus starting the year with a used permit for that site.)

**If you have a permit before you dig, do you spend it before you dig and then have it again after you're done digging?**

Finally, consider this odd case: you're in week 51. You spend three weeks moving to Mesopotamia (arriving in week 2 of the new year), and then start digging as part of the same move. Is this legal if you have no permit? (In theory, it would refresh in week 1, but the game doesn't break down your turn into components; it's "all one move.") If you had a permit, would you have a permit again once you were done digging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the key phrase in the rulebook is this one:

> At the end of his turn, the player pays any costs in weeks he has
>   incurred by moving his time marker.

By this token, you wouldn't be able to dig without permission just because, after the weeks taken up by movement, you would be "into next year".  If you start your turn in one year, then everything counts as taking place in that year; excavation permits can only flip at the *end* of a player's turn.

If you have a permit, you can of course use it at the very end of one year, and then have it flip back up again at the end of the same turn...